# Minecraft server problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't log into any Minecraft servers at all, not even locally hosted ones.

The error code I get is: `java.net.UnknownHostException: session.minecraft.net`. A tweet from a worker at Mojang told people that you could just flush your DNS, which I did. That didn't quite work, so I'm wondering if there are any other solutions out there?

I'm not quite sure what other information I have to give. I know that it's not just something with me because I know a lot of my friends also get this error once they try to log into a server, so it would be weird if all of our ISPs just cut us off.

Comment: Some information on the error messages you get would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question, but we still need some more information.  session.minecraft.net doesn't tell us anything; we're going to need more than that.

Comment: Could be a long shot, but you might be affected by the DNS Changer malware. Try going to http://www.dns-ok.us/ to see if your affected.

Comment: Nope, not a malware :/ 
A few friends of mine got the same problem, we've tried everything we could find on the web. Still not working, we'r almost out of ideas..

Comment: @mikkel If you figured it out, why don't you post what you did as an answer?  It might help people later.

Comment: When I ping the host session.minecraft.net, it gives me 54.243.79.232 as its IP address. Why don't you try adding the line `54.243.79.232 session.minecraft.net` 

 to the file %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts? Another IP is 50.19.234.138

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly, an `UnknownHostException` means it simply can't find `session.minecraft.net` which is highly likely what they use to authenticate players as they log into servers.

If the rest of the internet works, it's either a problem with Mojang's servers, or still your DNS.